# How to completely hide radio button options when a page loads using Jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm building a site with a shopping cart that doesn't give you access to the source code. I can edit the text on this page but I can't touch the forum fields or html.

Is it possible (using javascript or jquery) to hide the radio buttons on this payment page when the page loads so the customer can't edit payments on ALL pending orders at once? I'd like it to do the following:
1. hide both radio buttons when the page loads; 
2. select only the radio button for the selected order

```
<form id="AccountSettingsForm" action="/AccountSettings.asp" method="POST" onsubmit="if (typeof(Update_Hidden_State_Fields) == 'function') Update_Hidden_State_Fields();"><input type="hidden" name="modwhat" value="change_c">
<input type="hidden" name="BillingID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ShipID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CCardID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OrderPlaced" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="ReturnTo" value=""><br>
<table width="80%" border=0 align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#F7E26C">
<tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
<input type="radio" name="Apply_Payment_Method_To_All_Orders" value="" checked="checked" /><font color="#000000"><strong>Apply this payment method change to my Order#: 4 </strong></font><br />
<input type="radio" name="Apply_Payment_Method_To_All_Orders" value="Y"  />
<font color="#000000"><strong>Apply Payment Method To All Orders</strong></font></td></tr></table>
```

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Please mark one answer as accepted so you can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Start your page with the `AccountSettingsForm` element with the css property `display` set to `none`, then

```
<input class="rdbBtn" type="radio" name="Apply_Payment_Method_To_All_Orders" value="" checked="checked" /><font color="#000000"><strong>Apply this payment method change to my Order#: 4 </strong></font><br />
<input  class="rdbBtn" type="radio" name="Apply_Payment_Method_To_All_Orders" value="Y"  />

$('.rdbBtn').on('load',function(){
    $('AccountSettingsForm').css('display', 'inline-block');
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to set the display property to some random value. Block is for block elements, the default for input elements is *inline-block*, so that would seem a better value. But better again to allow it to return to its default or inherited style and set display to `""` (empty string);

Comment: This only a sample to show how to hide a html element, please lat me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had to think hard about what you posted because this is my first attempt at using jQuery. I finally figured it out! :) I didn't even think of adding the class first with jQuery and using CSS to hide it. I added the class rdbBtn first using:
    $( "form input:radio" ).addClass( "rdbBtn" );
There are actually more radio buttons in the form than the two I want to hide, so I inserted the addClass after the 2nd radio button. Is this the correct way to do it? I then added your script below the form. It works & loads perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Avoid to say thanks, just mark my answer as the correctly answer. Are you render the page on a dynamicly way, if so, this is the way, but if you are render through a html then you must add the class property in the html.